# How do we know that if we keep going with a step of two in the natural numbers we will land on a perfect square, either odd or even?

Tags: proof-writing, square-numbers, natural-numbers

I really need to use this for another proof that I have. Been struggling with this. Can I say that it is trivial?
It feels very common sense but would I need to specifically explain it if I do some proof?

Comment: Specifically how much you need to explain is often vague. A few good rules of thumb are "would someone at my level need to ask any questions about this proof?" and "would someone grading this KNOW that I'm not bluffing my way though this?". If the answers are no and yes respectively, then you're good to go. Otherwise, consider adding more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Mh, perfect squares are natural. If you try all even [odd] naturals, you will land on all even [odd] squares. So yes, trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are given the natural number $r$, then $r^2-r=r(r-1)$ is even and $$r^2=r+2\cdot\frac {r(r-1)}2$$ gives an explicit construction of a square which you will hit in due course.

It is trivial, as others have noted, that you will hit a square, but if you need a specific example of a square, this is an easy way ...

Answer (score 0):

You could very well call this trivial depending on the context, but you may also supply a quick proof if the situation demands it. Suppose you start at $n$ ($n\in \mathbb{N}$). Then $n^2 \geq n$. Since squaring preserves parity, you will reach $n^2$ by successively adding $2$ in a finite number of steps.